Matrix operator rewriting
Let $T,S\in B(H)$ and let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&S\\
T^{\ast}&0
\end{bmatrix}\in B(H\oplus H)
$$
How come that the following equality holds: $$\|S+T\|=\|A+A^{\ast}\|$$
If I understand correctly, each operator acts in its own Hilbert space, that is $S=(S,0)$ and $T=(0,T)$ therefore $+$ in the defintion of $A$ is a direct sum.
$$A+A^{\ast}=\begin{bmatrix}
0&S+T\\
S^{\ast}+T^{\ast}&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
and on the left hand side we have just $S+T$ which if we regard as $S=(S,0)$ and $T=(0,T)$ we get that
$$(S,T)=\begin{bmatrix}
0&S+T\\
S^{\ast}+T^{\ast}&0
\end{bmatrix}$$ which I dont see why it would be true.
I perhaps am misunderstanding something as this doesn't make much sense.
Thank you for your help!

It is not clear what is meant, if $S=-T$ then $|S+T| = 0$.

@copper.hat That's true, but in that case $A+A^*=0$ as well and the equality holds, so I don't see the issue here?

Start from the definition of the operator norm as well as the norm $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2}$ on $H\oplus H$ (follows from the induced inner product $\langle (x,y),(x',y')\rangle=\langle x,x'\rangle+\langle y,y'\rangle$) to compute:
\begin{align*}
\|A+A^*\|^2&=\sup_{(x,y)\in H\oplus H,\|(x,y)\|=1}\| ((S+T)y,(S+T)^*x) \|^2\\
&=\sup_{x,y\in H,\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2=1}\| (S+T)y\|^2+\|(S+T)^*x \|^2\tag1
\end{align*}
To see that this is equal to $\|S+T\|^2$—and hence to obtain $\|A+A^*\|=\|S+T\|$—we first upper bound this via
\begin{align*}
\|A+A^*\|^2&\leq\sup_{x,y\in H,\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2=1}\| S+T\|^2\|y\|^2+\|(S+T)^*\|^2\|x \|^2\\
&=\| S+T\|^2\sup_{x,y\in H,\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2=1}\|y\|^2+\|x \|^2=\| S+T\|^2
\end{align*}
where we used that $\|(S+T)^*\|=\|S+T\|$.
For the lower bound we start again from (1) and estimate
\begin{align*}
\|A+A^*\|^2&\geq \sup_{x,y\in H,\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2=1}\| (S+T)y\|^2\\
&\geq \sup_{y\in H,\|y\|^2=1}\| (S+T)y\|^2=\|S+T\|^2\,.
\end{align*}
Altogether this shows the desired equality of operator norms.

Hello Frederik, thank you for commenting. Might I Just ask one question, in the $\geq $ portion of the proof, why is the second inequality true, since there is just $y$ in the norm, It looks logical to me that the max is greater when $y$ can be of length $1$. Or perhaps you meant $\forall x,y\in H, ||x||^2+||y||^2=1$, therefore it is a bigger set than just $\forall y\in H,||y||^{2}=1$. Just want to confirm, sorry for bothering!

@VukStojiljkovic That's right, the reason precisely is that you go from the set ${(x,y):|x|^2+|y|^2=1}$ to the subset ${(0,y):|0|^2+|y|^2=1}={y:|y|=1}$ simply by setting $x=0$; hence the supremum cannot increase.

Dear Frederik,I would like to confirm one more thing if possible,in the first equality we used $$\begin{bmatrix}
0~~S+T\
S^{}+T^{}~~0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\
y
\end{bmatrix}=((S+T)y,(S^{}+T^{})x)$$ We get this expression for the norm by the definition, and then we use $$||(x,y)||^{2}=||x||^{2}+||y||^{2}$$For the $$||((S+T)y,(S^{}+T^{})x)||$$and we also use it for the condition, since we have $$||(x,y)||=1$$ and it is $$\Leftrightarrow ||(x,y)||^{2}=1 \Leftrightarrow ||x||^{2}+||y||^{2}=1$$.Then we proceed with CS and then we utilize the condition $||x||^{2}+||y||^{2}=1$

If possible, just comment whether my reasoning is all right, sorry for disturbing you, just want to make sure.

@VukStojiljkovic That's all correct, except for the fact that the inequality $|(S+T)y|\leq|S+T||y|$ follows from the definition of the operator norm (and not Cauchy-Schwarz). But yes, everything else is as you wrote it.

I meant that inequality, not CS, it was a typo, sorry. Thank you once again for your answer, it means a lot to me!

You should not identify $S$ and $T$ with $(S,0)$ and $(0,T)$. We have $A=(S,T^\ast)\circ\tau$ where $\tau\in B(H\oplus H)$ is defined by $\tau(x,y) = (y,x)$. Note that $\tau$ is self-adjoint:
\begin{align*}
\langle (z,w), \tau(x,y)\rangle
&=\langle (z,w), (y,x)\rangle\\
&=\langle z, y\rangle + \langle w, x\rangle\\
&=\langle w, x\rangle + \langle z, y\rangle\\
&=\langle (w,z), (x,y)\rangle\\
&=\langle \tau(z,w), (x,y)\rangle.\\
\end{align*}
Given any $X,Y\in B(H)$, it is tempting to write $\tau\circ(X,Y)=(Y,X)$, but this is not correct. Rather,
$$
\tau\circ(X,Y)=(Y,X)\circ\tau
$$
because $\tau\left((X,Y)(x,y)\right)=\tau(Xx,Yy)=(Yy,Xx)=(Yy,Xx)=(Y,X)(y,x)=(Y,X)\left(\tau(x,y)\right)$.
Since $A=(S,T^\ast)\circ\tau$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
A^\ast
&=\tau^\ast\circ(S,T^\ast)^\ast
=\tau\circ(S^\ast,T)
=(T,S^\ast)\circ\tau\\
\end{align*}
and $A+A^\ast=\left((S+T),(S+T)^\ast\right)\circ\tau$. That is,
$$
(A+A^\ast)(x,y)=\left((S+T)y,(S+T)^\ast x\right)\quad\forall x,y\in H.
$$
Obviously, $\tau$ is an isometry. Therefore
\begin{align*}
\|A+A^\ast\|
&=\left\|\left((S+T),(S+T)^\ast\right)\circ\tau\right\|\\
&=\left\|\left((S+T),(S+T)^\ast\right)\right\|\\
&=\max\left\{\|S+T\|,\|(S+T)^\ast\|\right\}\\
&=\max\left\{\|S+T\|,\|S+T\|\right\}\\
&=\|S+T\|.
\end{align*}

Benefitting from the $C^*$-Norm identity
$\,\|L^*L\| = \|L\|^2\,$ which any bounded linear operator $L$ on a Hilbert space satisfies, and the identity
$$\left\|\pmatrix{X&0\\0&Y}\right\|\:=\:\max\big\{\|X\|,\|Y\|\big\}$$
for a diagonal block matrix (which generalises the norm of a real or complex diagonal matrix being the largest absolute value of the entries),
one may derive the asked equality writing operators only:
\begin{align*}
\|A+A^\ast\|^2 \;=\; \big\|(A+A^*)^2\big\|
&\;=\;\left\|\pmatrix{0&S+T \\(S+T)^*&0}^2\,\right\| \\[2.7ex]
&\;=\;\left\| \pmatrix{(S+T)(S+T)^*&0\\0&(S+T)^*(S+T)}\right\| \\[2.7ex]
&\;=\;\max\Big\{\|(S+T)^\ast\|^2, \|S+T\|^2\Big\}\\[2ex]
&\;=\;\|S+T\|^2
\end{align*}

Can you reference me to the proof of the identity you used for the diagonal block matrix, that is the norm is max of the operator on the diagonal. Thank you for your answer and for your time!

Here is a MathSE-intern reference for it: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1404100/316749
